# How to add attributes to <script> tags with ZF2 and Assetic?

Tags: html, zend-framework2, assetic

So I have this Assetic module collection:

```
'collections' => array(
    'main_js' => array(
        'assets' => array(
            'js/jQuery.js',
            'js/main.js',
            etc...
        );
    );
);
```

Output:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
etc...
```

I need to add the defer attribute:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery.js" defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js" defer></script>
etc...
```

How to do this with ZF2 and Assetic?

Comment: As said in the github issue for this, it's not possible at the time (https://github.com/widmogrod/zf2-assetic-module/issues/125#issuecomment-73475248)